# Angular-route: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'angular.module')

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I'm building my Angular app, using require.js, angular.js and angular-route.js.

My main.js is as follows:

```
require.config({
  // alias libraries paths
  paths: {
    'angular': 'libs/angular',
    'domReady': 'libs/domReady',
    'angularRoute': 'libs/angular-route'
  },

// angular does not support AMD out of the box, put it in a shim
 shim: {
    'angular' : {'exports' : 'angular'},
 },

// kick start application
   deps: ['./bootstrap/bootstrap',
          './libs/angular-route',
          './libs/bootstrap'
         ]
});
```

Still I do got this strange error:

> [Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'angular.module')
>       (anonieme functie) (angular-route.js, line 24)
>       global code (angular-route.js, line 992)

Does someone knows how I can fix this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add angular js in dependency too.

Update from

```
deps: ['./bootstrap/bootstrap',
          './libs/angular-route',
          './libs/bootstrap'
         ]
```

to

```
deps: ['./bootstrap/bootstrap',
          'angular', // add require dependency of angular
          'angularRoute', // use path as set in require config
          './libs/bootstrap'
         ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved by doing this:

```
paths: {
    'angular'  : './libs/angular',
    'domReady' : './libs/domReady',
    'jQuery'   : './libs/jquery',
    'uiRouter' : './libs/angular-ui-router',
    'bootstrap': './libs/bootstrap'
},
// angular does not support AMD out of the box, put it in a shim
shim: {
  'angular': {
      exports: 'angular',
      deps: ['jQuery']

  },
  'uiRouter': {
      deps: ['angular']
  },
  'bootstrap': {
      deps: ['angular']
  },

 },
});

require(['./bootstrap']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had used a Yeoman scaffold to bootstrap my project, and found that the karma file was defaulting to not include the individual files in the browser tests.

Updating Angular to be included fixed this issue for me:

```
{pattern: 'bower_components/angular/angular.js', included: true },
{pattern: 'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js', included: false },
```